Automatically trigger Acquia pipelines job when content is updated
My team is fetching a large portion of our site's content at build time by using the i18n Gatsby plugin and downloading content from Drupal. The content we are fetching at build time rarely needs to be changed, but when it does, we now have to manually run an Acquia pipelines job and deploy the new artifact in order to display the updated content. This is inconvenient and time-consuming, especially since the content authors making these changes are typically not folks who have access to run a pipelines job or deploy a build.
Is there a straightforward way to automatically trigger a pipelines job when content is updated/added/deleted in Drupal? So far, the only solution my teammates and I have been able to think of is to use the Drupal Webhooks module to trigger a GitHub workflow, which would then do something like create a GitHub tag, which we could then configure to trigger a pipelines job. (We currently have our repo set up to start a pipelines job whenever a PR is opened in GitHub.)
Can we do this in a less roundabout way, for instance by using the Drupal Webhooks module to directly start a pipelines job in Acquia? From what we could tell, there isn't a way to do this, but it would be nice to avoid having to go through so many steps to set it up.
Also, is there a way to automatically deploy artifacts to a given environment? (I don't think we would want to do this in production, because it seems kind of risky, but might be nice to have it set up this way for one of our lower environments.)
Thank you in advance!

Did the idea of using the Acquia Cloud API, either via HTTP or with the Acquia CLI, come up in your discussions?

@cilefen Yes actually -- it seems like using the pipelines CLI client would be helpful if we could do that, but I got the impression it could only be used for local development? Is that not the case?

ACLI isn't installed on Acquia's servers (not on Next anyway, can't remember for the old-school version), so you'd need to trigger that from somewhere else, yeah. Triggering a github action would be my preferred way to do this, using ACLI as the tool to perform the trigger (for simplicity with authentication). But you could always just trigger the relevant HTTP call directly from a Drupal hook too

I see, thank you @Clive!

Ended up figuring it out! We were able to install the Acquia Pipelines CLI Client on one of our servers. Then, I created a custom Drupal module that starts a pipelines job whenever the content fetched at build time is updated. I used phpseclib3 in my module to ssh into the server and run a command to start a job.
For anyone who might stumble across this, my team also looked into switching from Gatsby to NextJS in order to use ISR (incremental static regeneration), which would allow us to achieve what we want without having to go to the effort of creating a whole custom module. But for various reasons, we've decided not to make the switch yet.
Thank you again to everyone who commented!
